# Как сказать "Thank you for honoring us by coming" по-русски?

Tags: выбор-слова, одним-словом

Context: We invited a celebrity a while ago and want to follow up by sending him an email showing our gratitude.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A relatively direct translation would be

> Спасибо, что почтили нас своим присутствием.

However, this is is a relatively old form of expressing gratitude for a visit. A more modern way would be something along these lines:

> Благодарим вас за честь, которую Вы оказали нам посещением нашего вечера (нашего концерта, нашей презентации, и так далее).

The above translates literally as "We are thanking you for the honor that you made us by visiting our event (our concert, our presentation, and so on)."

Comment: Is there a simpler way to say the modern version? I want to use a phrase whose grammatical construction I can understand.

Comment: @chubbycantorset Perhaps it would make more sense for me to explain the grammatical structure of the second sentence. I added a translation to the answer. The "we are" part is implied by the inflection of "благодарим"; the "by" in "by visiting" is implied by the declension of "посещением". Also note that the second version is more appropriate in writing, because it is very formal: it would be somewhat unusual to thank someone like this in a conversation (the same probably applies to the English original as well).

Comment: I don't think the first version is outdated, and it flows much better than the second.

Answer (score 3):

> Огромное спасибо, что Вы пришли, это большая честь для нас.

Comment: "Огромное спасибо" and "спасибо, что" are not perfect stylistically (though acceptable in everyday speech) and hence should not be used in formal invitations.

Comment: Большущее спасибо ;)